# Aligning two block horizontally: width of one should be determined by its content, the other should occupy all the remaining width

Tags: html, css

I've got two block elements in a container:

```
  <div class="container">

      <div class="element element_a">Element_A</div>
      <div class="element element_b">Element_B</div>

  </div>
```

The container occupies all the available width. The width is unknown/dynamic.

Element B's width should be determined by it's content (just like with `float` or `display: table`). The width of the content is unknown/dynamic.

Element A should occupy all the remaining width of the container.

Here's a screenshot of the desired result:

[image: desired result]

Here's a boilerplate for experiments: http://jsbin.com/xalazi/3/edit?html,css,output

There should be more than one way to do it, i suggest posting one approach per answer.

PS No JS!

Answer (score 2):

## `float` and `overflow: hidden`

Make use of `overflow: hidden` (or `overflow: auto`) to fill the remaining horizontal space.

(**NB**: For this to work the right-floated element B must appear first in your markup)

### Markup

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="b">element B</div>
    <div class="a">element A</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wpr {
    height:80px;
}
.b {
    background: aqua;
    float:right;
}
.a {
    background: maroon;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Demo

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4o1zxtsq/3/)

### Pros

- Very simple
- 100% browser support

### Cons

- Content of element A is unable to appear outside the element (e. g. with absolute positioning)

Comment: Ah! A witty `overflow: hidden` hack. Thank you for your contribution. Can you please update your answer with pros and cons?

Comment: pros and cons will depend on what you need to do. If you are looking to mimic a table - this approach could be problematic. Browser support is solid in that all browsers behave the same with this approach. Also you might want to add a min-width to element a. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o1zxtsq/4/)

Answer (score 2):

## Mimicking a table

#### HTML

```html
  <div class="container">

    <div class="element element_a">Element_A</div>
    <div class="element element_b">Element_B</div>

  </div>
```

#### CSS

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
}

.element_a {
  background-color: deeppink;
  width: 100%;
}

.element_b {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsbin.com/xalazi/4/edit?html,css,output

#### Pros

- Relatively simple
- Requires no extra markup
- 100% browser support

#### Cons

- The height becomes identical (equal to the height of the element with taller content)

Answer (score 1):

**FLEXBOX**

This is *very* easy to accomplish with flexbox.

```
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.element_a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* optional shorthand = flex: 1 0 auto; */
}

.element_b {
  /* no special css needed */
}
```

NOTE: You may need to add vendor prefixes based on what browsers you are targeting.

Set your container to flex and the elements automatically adjust to the content.

Setting .element_a's flex-grow to 1 will insure that it fills up the remaining space. Flex-shrink will make sure that .element_b's content doesn't overlap it.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yidekaqutozo/3/edit